# How do I get a super knockback in minecraft console? (1.4.2)

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I'm finishing a build on Minecraft, in a section of the adventure there are wither skeletons. You are supposed to knock them away and knockback 2 isn't enough. How can I increase the knockback strength?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could either keep enchanting until you get a higher level of knockback or you could download a map editor on your computer, such as the Universal Minecraft Editor (https://www.universalminecrafteditor.com/), but to get the maps on a newer console you will need to upload it from a ps3 or Xbox 360 which you can watch multiple videos on how to do that if you figure it out easily.